# window.location.href appending instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a little issue that I couldn't figure out. I have a slider and I want to change url when I click `prev` and `next` buttons. Here are my codes below but it doesn't work correctly. Every time I click the button, url appending instead of replacing.

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url + "page/" + 1;  // this number is dynamic actually
window.location.href = url;
```

For instance it displays; 
`stackoverflow.com/page` and I clicked `stackoverflow.com/page/1` and again `stackoverflow.com/page/1/page/2`

But I just want to replace it `stackoverflow.com/page/1` to `stackoverflow.com/page/2`

How can I fix it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window.location.href returns the entire url...

if you just want to add the "/page/1"

use

```
var url = window.location.origin;
url = url + "/page/" + 1;  // this number is dynamic actually
window.location.href = url;
```

though window.location.origin is undefined in windows 10

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

you could just replace the /page/#number#

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url .replace(new RegExp("/page/[0-9]"), "/page/2")
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 4):

All you want is a leading `/` in front of `page` to make a domain relative path

try

```
var url =  "/page/" + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to grab the page section and replace.

something like this:

```
let num = 2, url= "stackoverflow.com/page/1";
url = url.replace(/(page\/)([0-9]{1,})/, "$1"+num)
```